# Remove new line \n reading from CSV

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a CSV file which looks like:

```
Name1,1,2,3
Name2,1,2,3
Name3,1,2,3
```

I need to read it into a 2D list line by line. The code I have written almost does the job; however, I am having problems removing the new line characters `'\n'` at the end of the third index.

```
    score=[]

    for eachLine in file:
            student = eachLine.split(',')
            score.append(student)
    print(score)
```

The output currently looks like:

```
[['name1', '1', '2', '3\n'], ['name2', '1', '2', '3\n'],
```

I need it to look like:

```
[['name1', '1', '2', '3'], ['name2', '1', '2', '3'],
```

Comment: I have done it using the reader. Just wanted to see how else I could do it - learning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply call [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) on each line as you process them:

```
score=[]

for eachLine in file:
        student = eachLine.strip().split(',')
        score.append(student)
print(score)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splitlines`

**First method**

```
>>> s = '''Name1,1,2,3
... Name2,1,2,3
... Name3,1,2,3'''
>>> [ item.split(',') for item in s.splitlines() ]
[['Name1', '1', '2', '3'], ['Name2', '1', '2', '3'], ['Name3', '1', '2', '3']]
```

**Second method**

```
>>> l = []
>>> for item in s.splitlines():
...     l.append(item.split(','))
... 
>>> l
[['Name1', '1', '2', '3'], ['Name2', '1', '2', '3'], ['Name3', '1', '2', '3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's a \n, and a \n only,

```
score=[]

for eachLine in file:
        student = eachLine[:-1].split(',')
        score.append(student)
print(score)
```

Uses slicing to remove the trailing new line characters before the split happens.

EDITED, per the suggestions of the commentors ;) Much more neat.

Comment: Why not just use `strip`? And if you are going to slice, why not `[0:-1]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I'd say not [:-1]

Comment: Couldn't tell you why or why not to strip. I guess I personally just like to be more specific with what happens to my objects. Instead of leaving my string to the fate of the (heavily and well documented) strip function, I KNOW, that it's just going to be one off the end. No surprises (not that there should be any, using strip). Call it a quirk? Would there perchance be performance differences? @jonrsharpe ?

Comment: I'd expect the slice to be faster (`timeit` suggests ~ twice as fast on `'foo\n'`) , but if you don't have a blank line at the end of the file you cut the last character off the last line. Also, `strip` is more conventional, so there's less mental overhead in reading it.

Comment: Good point on the potential slicing of wanted data @jonrsharpe , gotta be carefu

Answer (score 0):

Use the rstrip function to identify \n at the end of every line and remove it.
See the code below for reference.

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'wb') as file: 
    for line in file:
        line.rstrip('\n')
        file.write(line)
```

Comment: Why not just `rstrip()` or `strip()`?