# I'm using append and its adding \n at the end of each element

Tags: python-3.x

The Code:

```
import csv

symbols = []
with open("I:/my500.csv") as f:
    for row in f:
        symbols.append(row)
```

The output:

```
['SPY\n', 'WMT\n', 'GLD\n', 'IBM\n']
```

Comment: better a dupe of [Remove new line \n reading from CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175874/remove-new-line-n-reading-from-csv)

Comment: It's not *adding* `\n`, that's *already there*

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you iterate through a file, the lines contain a newline. To solve this, you can `.rstrip()` them.

```
symbols = []
with open("I:/my500.csv") as f:
    for row in f:
        symbols.append(row.rstrip('\n'))
```

Even better, you can use a list comprehension:

```
with open("I:/my500.csv") as f:
    symbols = [row.rstrip('\n') for row in f]
```

Comment: Thanks it help a lot.