# How to delete newline character from string?

Tags: python

After parsing a csv file, i got a list like this:

```
['name', 'AGATC', 'AATG', 'TATC\n']
```

Is there any way that I can delete the newline (`\n`) character from the last element of the list so that the length of the element won't include the newline? I have tried the built-in `replace()` function but it did not work.

Comment: `\n` is not a null character. It's a newline character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a trailing newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-a-trailing-newline)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove new line \n reading from CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175874/remove-new-line-n-reading-from-csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's not a NULL, it's a newline
2. Yes! Just use the strip() method

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the final character:

```py
your_list = ['name', 'AGATC', 'AATG', 'TATC\n']
print(your_list)  # ['name', 'AGATC', 'AATG', 'TATC\n']

your_list[-1] = re.sub(r'\n$', '', your_list[-1])
print(your_list)  # ['name', 'AGATC', 'AATG', 'TATC']
```

Comment: Really? `re.sub` instead of a simple `strip()`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo And how do you know that the list element might not also start with whitespace (which the OP might want to retain) ?

Comment: Then use `rstrip('\n')`? Still seems simpler than compiling and running a regex...